# Activate Most Popular Items

Tags: sharepoint-online

I don’t see the features “View the Most Popular Items in a library” on my toolbar

How do I activate it.  I’m using SharePoint online

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/view-popularity-trends-and-most-popular-items) article. It might help you.

Comment: for some reason I don't see anywhere "Popularity Trends." .

Answer (score -1):

In order to see “Most popular Items” option for list enable the Cross Site publishing feature by going to Site settings-> Site collection features. Once you enable this you will be able to see the option.
[image]

Comment: site collection feature is missing on my site settings